# Can't get logstash to geoip locate from Netflow input

Tags: logstash, geoip

I'm trying to use Logstash to parse out and geolocate IP addresses from a Netflow source, it works to get the data into Elasticsearch, but it's not putting in the geoip info. Here's my config file that I'm using in logstash

```
input {
        udp {
                host => localhost
                port => 5555
                codec => netflow
        }
}

filter {
        geoip {
                target => "geoip"
                source => "ipv4_dst_addr"
                add_tag => ["geoip"]
                add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}"$
                add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" $
        }
}

output {
        stdout { }
        elasticsearch { host => "127.0.0.1" }
}
```

More info that might help, Using Logstash 1.4.2 and Elasticsearch 1.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck in figuring this one out?

If not, please note that you need to use a mutate to convert the coordinates to float.

However, the geoip filter in Logstash 1.3 and up adds a location field directly so you won't have to use add_field and you won't even have to use the converter. If you try these two solutions, please tell me how it goes. Thank you.

A side note: The recommended version to work with Logstash 1.4.2 of Elasticsearch is 1.1.1

Comment: I gave up on straight Netflow at the moment, and I'm using Bro to push flow data into Logstash, and found a good config file that adds in the geoip data. I plan on revisiting Netflow in a week or so because I'm going to need to be able to use that input format. I'll try your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent some time digging into this, and it ends up being something of a bug in the Netflow codec code (specifically, in the `IP4Addr` class in `netflow/util.rb`).

You should be able to work around this with a `mutate` filter, like this:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        convert => { 
            "[netflow][ipv4_src_addr]" => "string"
            "[netflow][ipv4_dst_addr]" => "string"
        }
    }
    geoip {
        source => "[netflow][ipv4_src_addr]"
        target => "src_geoip"
    }
    geoip {
        source => "[netflow][ipv4_dst_addr]"
        target => "dst_geoip"
    }
}
```

I've submitted a [pull request to fix this properly](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-netflow/pull/3), but in the time being, try that config.